# How to persist jbpm process to resume later?

Tags: jbpm

I gone through the jboss document
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.0/userguide/ch08.html.

My requirement is to persist jbpm process and resume the process later.
I was trying to build it as a spring boot application,tomcat embedded.
Could not find a better example.
Can anyone get me a reference pointer of the above question.A brief example will also be very helpful.Thanks in advance.